# TFS View History in VS2010 for all files under a Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm trying to view history in Visual Studio 2010 for all files included in a given Solution file via the Solution Explorer View.  I use TFS 2010 for source control, and I'm aware that I can get history for a folder recursively in Source Control Explorer.  My issue is that we have multiple projects in a root directory, all of which are included in a variety of solution files in that same directory (each solution file represents a deploy-able component, including some "shared code" between them).  I just want to view history on all of the files included in a given solution file, and not everything in this root directory.  When I right click on a solution or project in Solution Explorer and "View History", I just get history for that solution file or project file, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alas, this cannot be done with TFS as it is.

TFS Source control does not know if a file is a solution file or a text document.  It just stores it for you.  There is no parsing at all.  I can (and do) store Delphi project files in TFS.  There is no way for TFS to be able to understand and be smart about every file type that exists.

It would be nice if Solution explorer did this for you (as it is specific to your project).  But it does not.

You could create a custom plugin to TFS and Visual Studio to do what you are asking, but it would probably take longer than just manually checking the history of all the files in your solution.

Comment: +1. I would add that IMHO you should avoid using Source Control commands from the Solution Explorer's context menu entirely. I constantly see nasty problems caused by devs using Solution Explorer to apply SC commands instead of using the Source Control window - you'd think they work the same, but they don't!

Comment: If anyone ever find a plugin for this, please let me know. It would save quite a few clicks every time I need to see what the team has changed on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, it's an add-in extension 
[VS 2010 and VS 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dace3633-0b51-4629-85d4-c59cdce5bb3b)